# How to get a indexed document or document field value by document number (doc id)

Tags: python, whoosh

How do I get an indexed document or document field value by document number (doc id) using Whoosh?

For example, if I get a set of matches by `matcher=myquery.matcher(s)`; I can get matched doc num by `matcher.id`. How could we retrieve the document information by the doc num ?

I can't find any method in `whoosh.reading.IndexReader` allowing me to retrieve doc by docnum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find one solution via Whoosh documentation. Document information can be further retrieved by stored_fields method in [whoosh.searching.Searcher](https://pythonhosted.org/Whoosh/api/searching.html#whoosh.searching.Searcher). An example usage to get doc title by docnum can be achieved `searcher.stored_fields(matcher.id())["title"]`